# If I create a separate process for my service then will it still run on the application's main thread?

Tags: android, service

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) that I have read on android developer website it is clear to me that by default a [service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) runs on the application's main thread. Here is an extract from the android documentation...

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process unless you specify otherwise. If your service is going to perform any CPU-intensive work or blocking operations, such as MP3 playback or networking, you should create a new thread within the service to complete that work. By using a separate thread, you can reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors, and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities

But if I run my service in a separate process will it still run in the application's main thread?

I wrote this in my application's manifest file.

```
        <service android:name=".MyService"
        android:process=":my_service"/>
```

the process attribute will cause the service to run in a different process.

Comment: Please explain more and clearly with code thanks

Comment: I believe each process has its own "Main thread". https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: @Kuffs Thanks. This means that if I create a separate process for my service then my application main thread and service main thread will be different. right?